# Problemas con sourcetree

Tags: visual-studio, git, sourcetree

Tengo un stash y quiero aplicarlo a mi proyecto pero me da ese error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks stash apply stash@{0}
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    symmetry-web/bower.json
    symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/scripts/controllers/paciente/pulsera/pulsera.js
    symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/scripts/services/pulseraService.js
    symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/templates/paciente/pulsera/pulsera.html
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

Ya cambié esos archivos y nada, me da igual perder los cambios que hice ahora pero necesito los de ese stash. Trabajo con el visual Studio.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si no te importa perder esos cambios, puedes descartarlos

```
$ git checkout -- symmetry-web/bower.json symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/scripts/controllers/paciente/pulsera/pulsera.js symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/scripts/services/pulseraService.js symmetry-web/src/main/webapp/public/templates/paciente/pulsera/pulsera.html
```

y después reintentar aplicar el stash otra vez:

```
$ git stash apply
```

Comment: error: pathspec 'symmetry-web/bower.json' did not match any file(s) known to git me da este error con los demás ficheros tambien

Comment: Entiendo que estás ejecutándolo desde la carpeta raíz donde tengas el proyecto de git, ¿no?

Comment: Ya me funcionó, gracias. No me pillaba la ruta por un error ortográfico.  Ahora a pelearse con el Tomcat para que arranque jajaj